# Don't you think I haven't considered it?

Tags: meaning-in-context

While I was watching the British serials Merlin I heard this structure. As far as I have seen the negative forms of the questions are asked to emphasize I believe the otherwise and confirm this.

As an example;

> A: I came to your office yesterday but I couldn't find you there.
>   B: Don't you know I don't work on Saturdays?

In the example the person B believes A knows that he does not work on Saturdays and the question is just for confirmation.

In the serial the script was something like this:

> *Uther*: Because that's where most of the victims are. Let's isolate it, stop this disease from spreading.
>   *Arthur*: What about the people who live there?
>   *Uther*: Don't you think I haven't considered it? What else can I do? I have to protect the rest of the city.

Here in the last sentence the "Don't you think" part implies Uther believes Arthur thinks he hasn't considered in conjugation with my previous example. But the context makes me believe the opposite. However I would form this sentence like "Do you think I haven't considered it?". My questions are:

1) What do you understand from this structure here?

- a)You don't think I haven't considered it, do you?
- b) You think I haven't considered it but what else can I do?
- c) Something like "don't you start!", stop thinking I haven't considered it

2) What meaning difference do you get between;

- Do you think I haven't considered it?

and

- Don't you think I haven't considered it?

Comment: It should be 'don't you think I've considered it?' otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It seems that Uher begins: **Don't you think...** as part of an intended rhetorical question and then loses his way in the double negative.

Comment: You are right, Zalajbeg. "Do you think I haven't considered it?" is what he should have said.

Comment: If he begins '**don't** you think...', and intends a rhetorical question, it only makes sense to continue 'I've considered it?'

Comment: Firstly I had thought he may had said "Don't you think I have (already) considered it?" but after double checking I saw that it was "Don't you think I haven't considered it?". As you all agree it does not make sense, I will just accept it as a mistake in the script. Thanks!